# Brute Force Searching in C programming, reading a .fna file in C programming

Tags: c, codeblocks, brute-force, string-search

I am able to read a .fna and search for the pattern I want. But after I read the file, it is reading it line by line and not the whole. How can I extract a .fna file and store as a variable in C programming? Below are my code and the output I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 70000

void search(char* pattern, char* text)
{

    int M = strlen(pattern);
    int N = strlen(text);

    for (int x = 0; x <= N - M; x++) {
        int y;

        for (y = 0; y < M; y++)
            if (text[x + y] != pattern[y])
                break;

        if (y == M)
        {
            printf("Found pattern at position %d \n", x+1);
        }
    }}

int main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    char pattern[] = "GTTCTTT";
    char* filename = "D:\\Desktop\\NC_007409.fna";
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL)
        search(pattern, str);
        return 0;
}
```

[Output I gotten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TosXX.png)

Comment: "How can I extract a .fna file and store as a variable in C programming?" --> Simplistic approach, read once to find length, allocate memory, then `fread()` the whole thing.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content of a file as an array of bytes in two ways:

#### Allocate array manually (Simple way)

1. Get file size;
2. Allocate memory for the content of the file by using file size;
3. Read all content to file to the allocated memory.

#### Using file mapping (Advanced way)

The benefit of memory mapping a file is increasing I/O performance, especially when used on large files. For small files, memory-mapped files can result in a waste of slack space as memory maps are always aligned to the page size, which is mostly 4 KiB.

- [Memory-mapped file (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)
- [File Mapping (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping)